# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.activeandroid.TableInfo.getIdName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, activeandroid

i am getting this Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.activeandroid.TableInfo.getIdName()' on a null object reference
```

when i disable **Instant Run** i did not get any error my project works fine.

But i want to keep **instant Run** **Enabled**.
I find some where that if i want to **enabled Instant Run** i have to un-check the

> ReStart the Activity on code changes

but this did not work for me.

Any solution for this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried everything. this is the only thing that has worked.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

You don't have to turn off the instant run. Simply set

**Inside application node in `AndroidManifest.xml`, uninstall the app before running.**

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 8):

1. Verify your androidManifest, and add:

   `<application... >
   <meta-data
           android:name="AA_MODELS"
           android:value="myfullpackage.myentity1, myfullpackage.myentity2
           "
       />`
2. Verify if your class extends to `Model` and has constructor with `super();`

Answer (score 3):

plus :increment your AA_DB_VERSION in your manifest. That will force ActiveAndroid regenerate your schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle 2.0, then add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<meta-data
    android:name="AA_MODELS"
    android:value="com.myspace.model.modelName"/>
```

android:value should be the path of your model class.